# does the Facebook SDK (for iOS) break pre-existing deep links?

Tags: facebook

I have an iOS app that uses deep linking as part of an out-of-app authentication flow within a web view. Upon authentication, a redirect is made back to the app with the deep link prefix.

Ive installed the Facebook SDK because I wanted to track conversions, but after doing so, it seems to have disabled my deep linking functionality.

Is this expected, and if so, how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the SDK will overwrite any of the URL types that you have specified in the project info. So you need to re-add your original deep link(s)

[image]